# Laravel Singleton and Instance

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel Documentation I have read:

Binding A "Shared" Type Into The Container

```
App::singleton('foo', function()
{
    return new FooBar;
});
```

Vs.

Binding An Existing Instance Into The Container

```
$foo = new Foo;

App::instance('foo', $foo);
```

Due to the weakness of Laravel Documentation I cannot understand what is their difference.

Can anyone explain me?

Comment: Well, in second example, you can do some changes into the object before binding it into the container, if I am not mistaken i.e. `$foo = new Foo; $foo->setBar(100); App::instance('foo', $foo)`

Comment: I think I got what's going on there if yours explanation  is true

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checking in on Github, we can see that [the `singleton` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.1/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L178-L185) is a alias for the `bind` method, but set to be "shared" (basically, a singleton):

```
/**
 * Register a shared binding in the container.
 *
 * @param  string               $abstract
 * @param  Closure|string|null  $concrete
 * @return void
 */
public function singleton($abstract, $concrete = null)
{
    return $this->bind($abstract, $concrete, true);
}
```

On the other hand, [the instance method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.1/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L276-L283), it turns out, has a fairly simple use case:

```
/**
 * Register an existing instance as shared in the container.
 *
 * @param  string  $abstract
 * @param  mixed   $instance
 * @return void
 */
public function instance($abstract, $instance) { ... }
```

Basically you're passing in an existing object/value, rather than a Closure which returns an object/value. It returns that same object/value instance, which is effectively a singleton as well.

The difference is that an instance already exists when its bound to the container when using "instance", while its not yet created (it's lazy-loaded, thus saving potentially expensive operations until needed) via "singleton", when you pass in a closure who's responsibility is to produce the resulting object/value singleton.